# Entity Framework error: Unable to create a constant value of type '..'. Only primitive types

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using EF4. I am trying to convert the SQL to LINQ to EF and I am getting an error. I want EF to create and execute the SQL in the database (not do stuff in memory). The comparison is using primitive types which is an integer. How do I fix the error. I am thinking of using now group into syntax.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT   Restaurant.RestaurantID
         ,CASE  WHEN FoodType.FoodTypeID IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CustRating.Rating END AS Rating
 FROM               Restaurant Restaurant
 LEFT OUTER JOIN    CustRating CustRating 
 ON                 Restaurant.RestaurantID =   CustRating.RestaurantID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN    FoodType FoodType 
 ON                 FoodType.FoodTypeID = CustRating.FoodTypeID
 AND        FoodType.FoodTypeName = 'Taco'
```

**LINQ:** (testing in LinqPad)

```
var query =
        from restaurant in Restaurants
        from customerRating
        in CustomerRatings
            .Where( cr => cr.RestaurantID == restaurant.RestaurantID)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()

        from foodType
        in FoodTypes
      .Where(ft => ft.FoodTypeID == customerRating.FoodTypeID && ft.FoodTypeName == "Taco")
                      .DefaultIfEmpty()
        select restaurant;                  
           query.Dump();
```

**Error Message:**

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'CustomerRating'. 
Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead with a **join into** solution. I am still interested why I got the error with the other style.

```
var query = from restaurant in Restaurants
join cr in CustomerRatings on restaurant.RestaurantID equals cr.RestaurantID
into children
from child in children.DefaultIfEmpty()
join foodType in FoodTypes
on  child.FoodTypeID equals foodType.FoodTypeID   
into children2
from child2 in children2.Where(ft => ft.FoodTypeName == "Taco").DefaultIfEmpty()

select new { RestaurantID = restaurant.RestaurantID, 
FoodTypeID = (int?) child2.FoodTypeID,

Rating = ( (int?) child2.FoodTypeID == null?  0 : (int?)child.Rating )

}; 

query.Dump();
```

Comment: Your initial approach was wrong. It wasn't query you expected. Even if it would work you would get query with two cross joins.